# Add EditText in Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-edittext

I am working on adding text to a canvas.What I need to do is,when the user clicks on the screen an edit text is generated on the position the user clicks on.The user enters text and when he is done editing the text, save the text in list. I know how to get the position and add edit text. Edit Text add successfully but it is not editable and select able for further editing.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is simply to add an `EditText` whenever the user clicks your `View`, then you could do it without manual drawing. Take a look at this example (assuming we are in your Activitys `onCreate()` )

```
final RelativeLayout mainLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
mainLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
setContentView(mainLayout);
mainLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            return false;
        }

        EditText editText = new EditText(YourActivity.this);

        // Add whatever you want as size
        int editTextHeight = 70;
        int editTextWidth = 200;

        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(editTextWidth, editTextHeight);

        //You could adjust the position
        params.topMargin = (int) (event.getRawY());
        params.leftMargin = (int) (event.getRawX());
        mainLayout.addView(editText, params);
        editText.requestFocus();

        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can draw `EditText` on `Canvas`, Here is hint:

```
EditText et;
.
.
.
.
.   
et.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = et.getDrawingCache();
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, l, t, r, b, null);
```

You can create/initialize `EditText` at run time like this:

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
editText.setText("My Text");
editText.setWidth(180);         
editText.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```